# Azure DevOps Pipeline vstest.failed even all the unit tests are passed locallt

Tags: testing, visual-studio-code, azure-pipelines

There are a couple of test.cs files, and one of them totally passed the test in local VS. But when I checked in TFS it starts the CI build in Pipeline where I got vstest errors. I do not know why those tests passed in my local VS failed.
Here are my test assemblies and some warning logs.

[VsTest - testAssemblies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG2p4.png)

```
2022-03-04T04:16:15.7748891Z   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter : 14.0.2505.1
2022-03-04T04:16:17.1095350Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.Common.AccessRightsTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.Common.AccessRightsTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
2022-03-04T04:16:17.4128025Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.Common.AccessRightsTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.Common.AccessRightsTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
2022-03-04T04:16:17.4929738Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.Common.AccessRightsTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.Common.AccessRightsTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
2022-03-04T04:16:17.8100334Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.Common.ConditionFileLibrary\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.Common.ConditionFileLibrary\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
2022-03-04T04:16:18.0506287Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.Common.ConditionFileLibrary\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.Common.ConditionFileLibrary\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
2022-03-04T04:16:18.1288535Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.Common.ConditionFileLibrary\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.Common.ConditionFileLibrary\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
2022-03-04T04:16:18.4544944Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.ITSecurityTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.ITSecurityTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
2022-03-04T04:16:18.6957502Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.ITSecurityTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.ITSecurityTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
2022-03-04T04:16:18.7737037Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.ITSecurityTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.ITSecurityTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
2022-03-04T04:16:19.1559077Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.ITSecurityTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.3.2\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.ITSecurityTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.3.2\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
2022-03-04T04:16:19.2387265Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.ITSecurityTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.3.2\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'D:\a\2\_work\29\s\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security.ITSecurityTool\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.3.2\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
```

Comment: This is the test result.                                                                              Group Name: IFTagManagerTest
Group By: Hierarchy
Group Full Name: IFTagManagerTest
Duration: 0:00:27.2946169
0 test(s) failed
0 test(s) skipped
19 test(s) passed

Comment: The error in Azure Pipleline: 
Error: The process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe' failed with exit code 1
VsTest task failed.

Answer (score 2):

> Azure DevOps Pipeline vstest.failed even all the unit tests are passed locallt

According to the error message:

> Unable to load types from the test source
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.**TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll**.
> Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.

And the test content files you set:

[image]

This setting `!**\*TestAdapter.dll` may cause other assemblies sneak into the search path. Try adjusting the Test Assemblies to the following:

```
!**\*TestAdapter*.dll
```

Comment: Hi, it turns out I used some get product type methods which are different between Workstation and Server. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: This fixed a very similar issue in one of our build pipelines - many thanks!